# Java SQL query execution, problems in reading the ResultSet rows

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, postgresql, resultset

I'm writing simple Java code and I have to execute an SQL query on my Postgresql database.
The result of this database (I've checked manually) is a simple table made by one column and two integer numbers, like this:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot find any way to read these two rows.
My reading code is:

> _conn.setReadOnly(false);
>
> _stmt = _conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
>
> _stmt.setFetchSize(100);
>
> List< Short > lista = new List< Short >();
>
> _rs = _stmt.executeQuery(query);
>
> while (_rs.next())  {
>
> lista.add((short)_rs.getInt(1));
>
> }

This code only reads the 1st row, but there's no way to make it read the 2nd row.
The Short list "lista" contains always 1 element.
It's like if the ResultSet does not proceed in reading the second row...

How to read both the rows?

**EDIT**: I've tried with ArrayList but it does not work. I've added the code part for the _conn connection and the _stmt statement.
Here's the query:

```
            SELECT COUNT(bffK.biological_function_feature_oid) 
        FROM biological_function_feature AS bff 
        INNER JOIN biological_function_feature_unfolded AS bffu 
        ON bff.biological_function_feature_oid = bffu.term_oid 
        INNER JOIN (    SELECT DISTINCT ON (g.gene_oid, bffu.ancestor_oid) g.gene_oid AS ance_gene, bffu.ancestor_oid AS ance_oid, mf.feature_name AS feature_name, mf.feature_id AS feature_id, ef.name AS evidence, qf.name AS qualifier  
                FROM gene2biological_function_feature AS g2bff  
                INNER JOIN biological_function_feature AS bff  
                ON g2bff.biological_function_feature_oid = bff.biological_function_feature_oid   
                INNER JOIN biological_function_feature_unfolded AS bffu  
                ON bffu.term_oid = bff.biological_function_feature_oid  
                INNER JOIN metadata.feature AS mf ON bff.feature_type = mf.feature_id   
                INNER JOIN gene AS g ON g2bff.gene_oid = g.gene_oid  
                LEFT JOIN flag.evidence_flags AS ef ON g2bff.evidence = ef.id  
                LEFT JOIN flag.qualifier_flags AS qf ON g2bff.qualifier = qf.id     
                LEFT JOIN flag.inferred_flags AS fif ON fif.id = g2bff.inferred    
                WHERE g.gene_oid=(4060969) 
                AND (bff.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR bff.is_obsolete IS NULL)    
                AND (g.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR g.is_obsolete IS NULL)
                AND distance=1   
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (g.gene_oid, bff.biological_function_feature_oid)   
                g.gene_oid AS ance_gene, bff.biological_function_feature_oid AS ance_oid, 
                mf.feature_name AS feature_name, mf.feature_id AS feature_id,  
                ef.name AS evidence, 
                qf.name AS qualifier   
                FROM gene2biological_function_feature AS g2bff  
                INNER JOIN biological_function_feature AS bff  
                ON g2bff.biological_function_feature_oid = bff.biological_function_feature_oid    
                INNER JOIN metadata.feature AS mf ON bff.feature_type = mf.feature_id    
                INNER JOIN gene AS g ON g2bff.gene_oid = g.gene_oid  
                LEFT JOIN flag.evidence_flags AS ef ON g2bff.evidence = ef.id  
                LEFT JOIN flag.qualifier_flags AS qf ON g2bff.qualifier = qf.id     
                LEFT JOIN flag.inferred_flags AS fif ON fif.id = g2bff.inferred    
                WHERE g.gene_oid=(4060969) 
                AND (bff.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR bff.is_obsolete IS NULL)   
                AND (g.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR g.is_obsolete IS NULL)  
                AND ef.name NOT IN ('IEA', 'ND') 
            ) 
        AS unf ON unf.ance_oid = bffu.ancestor_oid 
        INNER JOIN gene AS gK on gk.Gene_oid=ance_gene 
        INNER JOIN biological_function_feature AS bffK 
        ON bffK.biological_function_feature_oid = bffu.ancestor_oid 
        LEFT JOIN flag.evidence_flags AS efK  
        ON evidence = efK.name 
        LEFT JOIN flag.qualifier_flags AS qfK  
        ON qualifier = qfK.name 
        WHERE bffu.distance=1 AND (bff.biological_function_feature_oid) IN (217538)
        AND evidence NOT IN ('IEA', 'ND')   
        UNION 
        SELECT COUNT(bffK.biological_function_feature_oid) 
        FROM biological_function_feature AS bff 
        INNER JOIN biological_function_feature_unfolded AS bffu 
        ON bff.biological_function_feature_oid = bffu.term_oid 
        INNER JOIN (    SELECT DISTINCT ON (g.gene_oid, bffu.ancestor_oid) g.gene_oid AS ance_gene, bffu.ancestor_oid AS ance_oid, mf.feature_name AS feature_name, mf.feature_id AS feature_id, ef.name AS evidence, qf.name AS qualifier  
                FROM gene2biological_function_feature AS g2bff  
                INNER JOIN biological_function_feature AS bff  
                ON g2bff.biological_function_feature_oid = bff.biological_function_feature_oid   
                INNER JOIN biological_function_feature_unfolded AS bffu  
                ON bffu.term_oid = bff.biological_function_feature_oid  
                INNER JOIN metadata.feature AS mf ON bff.feature_type = mf.feature_id   
                INNER JOIN gene AS g ON g2bff.gene_oid = g.gene_oid  
                LEFT JOIN flag.evidence_flags AS ef ON g2bff.evidence = ef.id  
                LEFT JOIN flag.qualifier_flags AS qf ON g2bff.qualifier = qf.id     
                LEFT JOIN flag.inferred_flags AS fif ON fif.id = g2bff.inferred    
                WHERE g.gene_oid=(4060969) 
                AND (bff.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR bff.is_obsolete IS NULL)    
                AND (g.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR g.is_obsolete IS NULL)
                AND distance=1   
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (g.gene_oid, bff.biological_function_feature_oid)   
                g.gene_oid AS ance_gene, bff.biological_function_feature_oid AS ance_oid, 
                mf.feature_name AS feature_name, mf.feature_id AS feature_id,  
                ef.name AS evidence, 
                qf.name AS qualifier   
                FROM gene2biological_function_feature AS g2bff  
                INNER JOIN biological_function_feature AS bff  
                ON g2bff.biological_function_feature_oid = bff.biological_function_feature_oid    
                INNER JOIN metadata.feature AS mf ON bff.feature_type = mf.feature_id    
                INNER JOIN gene AS g ON g2bff.gene_oid = g.gene_oid  
                LEFT JOIN flag.evidence_flags AS ef ON g2bff.evidence = ef.id  
                LEFT JOIN flag.qualifier_flags AS qf ON g2bff.qualifier = qf.id     
                LEFT JOIN flag.inferred_flags AS fif ON fif.id = g2bff.inferred    
                WHERE g.gene_oid=(4060969) 
                AND (bff.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR bff.is_obsolete IS NULL)   
                AND (g.is_obsolete NOT IN ('t') OR g.is_obsolete IS NULL)  
                AND ef.name IN ('IEA', 'ND') 
            ) 
        AS unf ON unf.ance_oid = bffu.ancestor_oid 
        INNER JOIN gene AS gK on gk.Gene_oid=ance_gene 
        INNER JOIN biological_function_feature AS bffK 
        ON bffK.biological_function_feature_oid = bffu.ancestor_oid 
        LEFT JOIN flag.evidence_flags AS efK  
        ON evidence = efK.name 
        LEFT JOIN flag.qualifier_flags AS qfK  
        ON qualifier = qfK.name 
        WHERE bffu.distance=1 AND (bff.biological_function_feature_oid) IN (217538)
        AND evidence IN ('IEA', 'ND')
```

Comment: What's the `query` look like?

Comment: Hi guys. I did not solved my problem, but I changed the query in order to get 2 rows and two columns as output, and then the ResultSet worked fine. I changed the query SELECT parts this way:  `SELECT COUNT(bffK.biological_function_feature_oid), 'IEA ND' FROM`  [...] `SELECT COUNT(bffK.biological_function_feature_oid), 'NON-IEA NON-ND' FROM [...]`. The output became: first row 'IEA ND' | 0 ; second row: 'NON-IEA NON-ND'| 1. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface, try using something like ArrayList

```
List< Short > lista = new ArrayList< Short >();

_rs = _stmt.executeQuery(query);

     while (_rs.next()) {

lista.add((short)_rs.getShort(1));

}
```

Comment: That query is too scary for me. Its not the code snippet, which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface, therefore you cannot instantiate directly rather than using its one of implementation like ArrayList. Also note that count is a keyword in PG, so avoid using keyword as identifiers. Working solution:

```
pst = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM demo");
List<Short> lista = new ArrayList<Short>();
rs = pst.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
   lista.add((short)rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be an issue with syntax. Do you also get one row when you run the query against the database? Perhaps you can post your SQL query too.

Comment: I've inserted the query and some code details about connection and statement. Maybe are they the problem?